# Is it advisable to have two Windows or multiple Windows in one SSD?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd

I am not sure if my question is allowed to ask here, if not please let me know.
Here is the situation.

I am going to pay someone to build a PC for me.
The person who will build the PC for me asked me some question about something like faster Hard Disk, I don't know what exactly he meant, but I have written down what he said, it is called SSD.
I have done some quick online reading about what SSD does. If I understand it correctly, SSD is like HDD in some ways (or mabye be many ways, I don't know SSD anyways) but runs more faster than HDD does.

Since I have the CDs of Windows 7 and 10, I am going to ask him to install both the OS in that SSD so that it will have two Windows for me to choose from, but I am not sure if it is advisable to do it.

I am sorry if my question is not good. Thank you.

Merry Christmas!

Comment: SSD is a hard drive replacement that uses memory cells rather than spinning platters, its a solid state device. I see no reason not to to run 2 OS's on one drive, its done all the time. http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2404258,00.asp

Answer (score 1):

SSD is an improvement over HDD in pretty much everything, but their function is exactly the same, which is to store data. Regarding your second question, you can install two operating systems on the same hard disk and choose to boot from either of them at boot time, but you might want to consider a virtual machine instead.

Comment: Thank you, but what is a virtual machine. I have no idea. I am sorry

Comment: You can have several operating systems running at the same time, and you can switch between them by Alt+Tab.